# PHP form display only one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I am performing a left join to display users and their values in a html form.

```
SELECT users.user, table2.total FROM users LEFT JOIN table2 on users.user = table2.total WHERE users.user = 'marketing' OR users.user = 'sales';
```

I have now added an insert that will add a new row if the date of the previous is not the current day:

```
("INSERT INTO data(total, user, Date) VALUES(:total, :user, CURDATE()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total=VALUES(total)", array('total' => $total, 'user' => $user), $conn);
```

Now however I am finding that my form is displaying every entry for the user, including previous days. Is there a way I can alter the left join statement so that it includes only the current day, and just a username(a blank total value) if there is no entry for the current day in table2?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your query to this one:

```
$currentDate = date(Y-m-d);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT users.user, table2.total
                      FROM users LEFT JOIN table2 on users.user = table2.total 
                      WHERE users.user = 'marketing' OR users.user = 'sales'
                      AND table2.Date = '$currentDate'");
```

If this doesn't help. Please provide more data of your tables for us to see its structure.

Comment: Thanks! I got it! I used your example and did the following: `SELECT users.user, table2.total
FROM users LEFT JOIN table2 on users.user = table2.total AND $table2.date = CURDATE() WHERE users.user = 'marketing' OR users.user = 'sales'`

Answer (score 0):

Alter your left join statement and include data table into it since you have indicated from this table the date when the data is added and put a condition like:

```
`data`.`Date` = CURDATE()
```

This should go to your where clause.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I tried this and as there will not always be an entry for a user in table2, it does not show all users, only the ones that have a current or previous entry in table2. I need all users, and if they have an entry in table2 I need the most current.